# How do I keep Copilot inline suggestions, but disable the normal IntelliSense drop-down, in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I would like to *keep* the grayed-out Copilot suggestion in the `fib` screenshot, and I would like VSCode to *stop* showing the drop-down in the `Foo` screenshot. Is this possible?

[fib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAUKx.png)

[foo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUeuy.png)

I've Googled for this question, and tried finding the right setting myself.

---

This question has been marked a duplicate, but the linked "duplicate" question is different from my question. In the linked question, the person is asking how to make IntelliSense and inline suggestions work together. I want IntelliSense to go away / stop popping up.

Comment: stack overflow has become so crappy, just a bunch of trolls running around getting their jollies closing legitimate questions